# Regular expression to match a standalone = character

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a single standalone '=' character with a regular expression.

For example, for this code

```
if(y == 5 || x = 1) {
  Do something ...
}
```

I want to match to the single '=', and not the "==". I've tried a lot of combinations of regular expression strings but I still can't get a match on the correct position.

Comment: Why are you using regex to parse code? Unless this is a very simple tool, you'll want something more robust.

Comment: Look for a = that's neither preceded or followed by another =?

Comment: If I use that particular method, it will match the second "=" in the "==" portion.

Comment: you can read single character than compare '=' if is equal then read next and compare it '=' if is equal do nothing, otherwise do necessary process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by using a negative lookbehind and a positive lookahead:

```
(?<!=)=(?!=)
```

Example: https://regex101.com/r/uV5eC5/1

For more information about lookahead/lookbehind, read [Regex lookahead, lookbehind and atomic groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973436/regex-lookahead-lookbehind-and-atomic-groups)

Comment: If your regex parser supports this.

Comment: Thanks for linking the tool, this should work. I just have to convert it to the C++ regex syntax.

Comment: This would only work with Boost library or PCRE library. C++11 regex follows ECMAScript regex, which doesn't support look-behind.

Answer (score 0):

fbo's solution certainly is more elegant, but if it needs to be done in JS, which doesn't have look-behinds, you could do it with

```
[^=]=[^=]
```

Since it appears to be code you're checking, there will always be a character before and after the `=`, and therefore this test that neither of them is another `=`.

Comment: Both your answer and his worked after converting it to the C++ regex syntax.

Comment: Note that if you want to use replace afterwards, it would also replace the symbol before and the symbol after `=`. So, you could capture them as separate groups: `([^=])(=)([^=])` and then use `$1==$3` for the replace (assuming you want to replace `=` with `==`).